# Delphi, OmniXML - XML binding?

Tags: delphi, omnixml

I'm trying out OmniXML after years of working with the default msxml implementation.
I have several xml structures (some of which are pretty massive) for which I originally created a binding using the Delphi wizard. The binding was then edited manually to fix errors and what not.

First question: is there a (somewhat) easy way to create such a binding for OmniXML? I suspect not, but you never know... I started editing my structures by hand to try and make the interfaces and classes fit into omniXML, but it is quite a bit of (very tedious) work

Second question: In some of the demos, and online, it would seem that the "data binding" (for want of a better term) is done by inheriting the classes defined in OmniXMLPorperties (TGpXMLxxxx). So I started toying with that. Is there an advantage, at least in my case, to defining my data-binding this way as opposed to trying to recycle the one created by the wizard?

Thanks!

PS: In case it matters, I'm using Delphi XE2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi's native XML Data Binding is not tied to any particular XML DOM vendor implementation.  It is based on `TXMLDocument` and related interfaces, which then access vendor-specific DOM interfaces internally.

On Windows, MSXML is the default DOM vendor used.  On Mac OSX, ADOM/OpenXML is the default DOM vendor used.  But you can change which DOM vendor is used.  You just have to assign the DOM vendor's name to the global `DefaultDOMVendor` variable in the `Xml.XmlDom.pas` unit, and make sure a corresponding DOM implementation has been registered via `RegisterDOMVendor()` (for MSXML and ADOM/OpenXML, simply add the corresponding DOM implementation unit in your `uses` clause - `Xml.Win.msxmldom` for MSXML, `Xml.adomxmldom` for ADOM/OpenXML - as they call `RegisterDOMVendor()` internally).

So in this case, you would simple find (or make) a DOM implementation wrapper for OmniXML so it can plug into `TXMLDocument`, then register it with `RegisterDOMVendor()`, and set the `DefaultDOMVendor` variable to the registered DOM name.

Comment: And becouse OmniXML is MSXML compatible that should not pose a problem.

Comment: Nice, that sounds relatively simple! Thanks Remy, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Bourgui please let us know what your try results in.